# Convolution/weighted average of two arrays in python

Tags: numpy, convolution, integral, weighted-average

I have an equation that I need to calculate numerically, but I am having doubts about my approach. I also put this question on the [Computational Science stack exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42577/convolution-weighted-average-of-two-arrays-in-python) with a bounty.

This is the equation I need to program:
[image: integral]

where $\chi$ is a volume mixing ratio in the stratosphere, $\chi_0$ is a volume mixing ratio in the troposphere and G is an age spectrum (a distribution of times it takes an air parcel to travel from troposphere to stratosphere).  G is an inverse Gaussian:

[image: inverse Gaussian]

where t' is defined as the transit time $\Delta$t divided by $\Gamma$.
The tropospheric volume mixing ratios as a function of time form an almost linear curve. I'll put the curves below (ignore the dashed lines). The time lags are with respect to 2009, i.e. a time lag of 1 corresponds to 2008 etc. Now I need to apply the first equation to these two curves numerically. I have tried `numpy.convolve(chi0[::-1], G, mode='same')` and variations thereof, but I'm having doubts about the results, so any feedback is greatly appreciated.
So to state it clearly, my question is: How do you convolve the tropospheric curve with the spectrum G, as prescribed by the first equation?

[image: Age spectrum]

[image: Tropospheric reference]